# How do I remove the recently added section in Music?

Tags: iphone, ios, music.app

I recently updated my old iPhone 5 to iOS 9.

One of the things I don't like about the new music player is that when I start it up after I turned on my iPhone, half the screen is taken up by useless stuff, the main offender is the "recently added" section.

Is there a way I can get rid of this recently added section?

Answer (score 3):

No, that section can't be removed.  Many people, including me, would like to be able to customize the start screen like this but I haven't been able to find any credible info on how to do this.

Answer (score -1):

You can hide it is all I can find.... select "Recently Added" in the left column, then [Right]Click > [Uncheck/Tick] Recently added. Will not show when you open iTunes in future... Not perfect but a start

Comment: the question is not talking about itunes but the music app